# passport don't redirect to 'failureRedirect' upon failure with facebook

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-facebook

Im using passport to authenticate a user through Facebook.

The `successRedirect` works great [I'm redirecting into `http://localhost:3000/success#_=_`], but the `failureRedirect` doesn't, i'm getting this:

```
FacebookAuthorizationError: Login Error: There is an error in logging you into this application. Please try again later.
[I'm getting this in my browser-> http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback?error_code=1349003&error_message=Login+Error%3A+There+is+an+error+in+logging+you+into+this+application.+Please+try+again+later.#_=_
```

Those are my settings:

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    console.log(user);
    done(null, 'this is the user');
})

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    console.log(id);
    done(err, {message: 'this is the user'});
});

router.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'));

router.get(
    '/auth/facebook/callback',
    passport.authenticate('facebook',
        {
            successRedirect: '/success',
            failureRedirect: '/login',
        }
    ),
);

const FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;

const facebookStrategy = new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: staretegy.clientId,
    clientSecret: staretegy.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: staretegy.callbackURL,
    profileFields: [
        'id',
        'first_name',
        'middle_name',
        'last_name',
    ],
}, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    done(null, {user: profile});
});

passport.use(facebookStrategy);
```

As i read in the docs i expected to be redirect to the `/login.`

`/login` can be accessed by the browser. (i've also tried to put this full URL path: `failureRedirect: http://localhost:3000/login` but it won't work, similar URL works with the `successRedirect`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems an [open issue](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook/issues/255) and the main repository barely supported. But you can try to use [this fork](https://github.com/passport-next/passport-facebook).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60185171/how-to-catch-facebookauthorizationerror-in-passport-facebook-passport-js) and have found a way to handle the error using a middleware error handler (see fbErrorHandler below):

```
const   express     = require('express'),
        router      = express.Router(),
        passport    = require('passport');

    router.get(
        '/facebook', 
        passport.authenticate('facebook')
    );

    function fbErrorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
        // I use flash, but use whatever you want to communicate with end-users:
        req.flash('error', 'Error while trying to login via Facebook: ' + err);
        res.redirect('/login');
    }

    router.get('/facebook/callback',
        passport.authenticate(
            'facebook', 
            { 
                failureRedirect: '/login',
                failureFlash: true
            },
        ),
        fbErrorHandler,
        (req, res) => {
            // Successful authentication
            res.redirect('/authenticated');
        }
    );

    module.exports = router;
```